# sorting file based on a column in perl

Tags: perl, sorting

Input file :

```
gi|73912712|ref|NP_001027538.1| Cullin_binding  187-300 0.00e+00    2   EKLRNSLDYLRSVLN-DATSFKLIYRYAFDFAREKDQRSLDLNTAKCMLGLLLGKT-WPLFPVFNQFLEQSKYKVINKDQWCNVLEFSRTINLDLSNYDEDGAWPVLLDEFVEWYK    0.1 -   -
gi|189526861|ref|XP_001920428.1|    Pfam-B_8567 184-326 0.00e+00    27  EKKSSAQAAVEHSDRIFTELIRSLTKKRTEVRGEIRAQEKRETQQIIGYIQKREQEISNLQKRNDKLGQILCTEDYIHFFQNYSSHSTKIPYTLPKK--VHDDlVTFREVDQSVSELKRKLDEVCEEHMGKISKKVADVHIIQSA   0.1 -   -
gi|189526861|ref|XP_001920428.1|    zf-B_box    140-177 0.00e+00    2   QQQICPQHHKA-LEIYCYEDKRCICVLCLGQ-HRGHKTVS    0.1 -   -
```

I need to sort the whole file rows based on **187-300** column.

Output should be in ascending order of this column value (140<184<187) so,

```
gi|189526861|ref|XP_001920428.1|    zf-B_box    140-177 0.00e+00    2   QQQICPQHHKA-LEIYCYEDKRCICVLCLGQ-HRGHKTVS    0.1 -   -
gi|189526861|ref|XP_001920428.1|    Pfam-B_8567 184-326 0.00e+00    27  EKKSSAQAAVEHSDRIFTELIRSLTKKRTEVRGEIRAQEKRETQQIIGYIQKREQEISNLQKRNDKLGQILCTEDYIHFFQNYSSHSTKIPYTLPKK--VHDDlVTFREVDQSVSELKRKLDEVCEEHMGKISKKVADVHIIQSA   0.1 -   -
gi|73912712|ref|NP_001027538.1| Cullin_binding  187-300 0.00e+00    2   EKLRNSLDYLRSVLN-DATSFKLIYRYAFDFAREKDQRSLDLNTAKCMLGLLLGKT-WPLFPVFNQFLEQSKYKVINKDQWCNVLEFSRTINLDLSNYDEDGAWPVLLDEFVEWYK    0.1 -   -
```

Comment: Does it have to be done with perl? Why not the `sort` command?

Comment: I don't think this deserves a downvote. It may not be obvious to everyone else, but the output is from a DNA similarity search, and goal appears to be to sort the matches by the position. Why? I don't know, but that's what it is happening. My answer is the simplest but not the most general (given the ranges), still that would be my approach to the problem.

Comment: @SES I didn't downvote but the question is off topic according to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

Comment: See also: [Sorting an array or table by column in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112465/how-to-sort-an-array-or-table-by-column-in-perl/27135781#27135781)

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly the the output of BLAST (or something similar) that has been parsed into this format. You can probably use a BLAST parser (like those in BioPerl) to manipulate your data. If all you want is to sort the 3rd field in this file though, something like this should work (using unix sort, not perl):

```
sort -n -k 3.1,3.3 file > out
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ane'
  push @r, [ $_, $F[2] =~ /(\d+)/ ];
  END {
    print $_->[0] for sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @r;
  }
' file
```

Comment: +1, but I think OP wants to sort on the whole column (ie. `187-300`) and not `187` alone.

Comment: @M42 OP mentions `140<184<187` which are all numbers before dash, and sample output follows that line of thought?

Comment: It isn't really clear, he said also `I need to sort the whole file rows based on 187-300 column.`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sorting based upon the length of each row?

In Perl's [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) function, you can specify a subroutine that provides a basis of your sorting.

Perl passes to the subroutine two data items, `$a`, and `$b`. These represent two items in your array you're sorting. You use whatever your criteria is to determine the sorting criteria, and pass back a `-1` if `$a` should be sorted before `$b`, a `0` if they're equal, or a `1` if `$a` should be sorted after `$b`.

Two functions, [<=>](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) for numerics and [cmp](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) for strings can be used to help create the correct return value. These automatically return `-1` if the argument on the left is less than the argument on the right, `0` if they're both equal, and `1` if the argument on the right is less than the argument on the left.

Assuming you're sorting on the [length](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) of the string:

```
my @lines = <$fh>;
close $fh;
for my $line ( sort by_length @lines ) {
   print $line;
}

#
# Sort by length of the line
#
sub by_length {
    return length $a <=> length $b;
}
```